# Oracle Identity Manager Design Console, How to create an IF statement for an adapter task

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements, task, adapter, oim

I'm trying to create an conditional for a task inside of an adapter.

[image: Problem]

Inside this adapter we have these variables, i need to take 1 of then an use the value to do a validation.

[image: Variables]

I've been try to create a Logic Task to evaluate it, but it doesnt work the logic is wrong and im new using this design console and the adapters.

I can't use the main code, i have it, but the idea is to create that conditional instead touch the code

The validation that i need to do is:

- Taking the variable "processFormAttrUserID" see the value what it takes and evaluate if begings with the Letter A or B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a new adapter for this. (That way you can still use the old adapter or reference it if you need to)

In the new adapter build out the logic as you go, the variable i used to base my logic off of was 'Usertype'. Then nest the action within the logic statement. Where i placed 'Set Adapter Return value' you could implement java tasks.

[image]

You can also use tcUtilStringOperations to perform the substring tasks and assign them to a variable to be used with your logic

[image]